# react js show data separately in each row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am facing issue in react js. I want to show `customer full name` data separately in each row div
but they come together in single row div

My Code:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      appointmentdata:[]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/v1/appointments`)
    .then(res => {
      const appointmentdata = res.data;
      this.setState({ appointmentdata });
    })
  }


  render() {

    let FullName = null;
    if (this.state.appointmentdata && this.state.appointmentdata.length) {
        FullName = (
          this.state.appointmentdata.map((data, index) => {
            return (
                <p key={index}>{data.cust_full_name}</p>
            )
        })
       )
    }

    return (
      <div>
      { FullName }    //mirza
     </div>
      <div>
      { FullName }    //ahmed
     </div>
      <div>
      { FullName }    //mubeen
    </div>

      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

console.log data

```
0: {id: "2", location_id: null, cust_full_name: "mirza", staff_any: "0", …}
1: {id: "3", location_id: null, cust_full_name: "ahmed", staff_any: "0", …}
```

Result:
[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0g13.png)

Expected Output:
[Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KvRw.png)

show `customer full name` data separately in each row div

What should i do? anyone help?

Comment: Try including ```<br />``` tag after ```p``` tag like, ```<p key={index}>{data.cust_full_name}</p> <br />``` ..

Comment: `<br/>` it not working [@Maniraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7785337/maniraj-murugan)

Comment: I guess, there's missing css-tag, a lot.

Comment: no i don't use css tin my code[@Yevgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11299053/yevgen-gorbunkov)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
render() {
  return (
     <>
       {this.state.appointmentdata && 
          this.state.appointmentdata.map((data, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                  <p>{data.cust_full_name}</p>
                </div>
            )
          })
       }
     </>
  )
}
```

Comment: ok let me check [@Lokesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10190406/lokesh)

Comment: bro you show my expected output [@lokesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10190406/lokesh)

Comment: No I want to show data in separate div with each fullname [@lokesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10190406/lokesh)

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` tag has already done its job as per your output image, but I think you need more space b/w 2 rows

You can add `<br/>` to add more space b/w two rows , Here is the code snippet you can use

```
return ([
    <p key={index}>{data.cust_full_name}</p>,
    <br/>
])
```

---

**OR**

You can apply css style to your `<p>` tag or `whatever tag` contains your fullname, like `padding` or `margin` for more space ( **suggested by @YevgenGorbunkov** in comment )

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-div-style?file=index.js)** (with and without style)

Comment: Wouldn't CSS styling be more appropriate than stacking `<br/>`?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, yes that's also a good option. this struct first to me so...

Comment: i don't use css in my code[@Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)

Comment: I want to show data in separate div with each fullname[@Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)

Comment: @adnankhan, then you can use the given code snippet inside your `FullName ` function

Comment: @adnankhan, `Problem: just show data separately in each row but they come together in single row` that's because of style

Comment: same result, they both together in div [@vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)

Comment: @adnankhan, please check given working demo , that might help you to understand,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-div-style?file=index.js

Comment: thanks your time [@vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)

Comment: one more thing i wil ask?[@Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)

Comment: i want to show data in row wise not in column what should i do?[@vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)

Comment: create a demo just like me with your code and style, then I can help you more